# Does acrylic resin in acetone react with the same acrylic resin in ethyl acetate?

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, polymers, safety, solvents

I am not at all familiar with organic chemistry. I am working in museum conservation where an acrylic resin (such as [Paraloid B-72](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraloid_B-72)) is mixed acetone and sometimes ethyl acetate to produce a resin for marking objects.

Would there be any potentially dangerous byproducts produced if a 20% solution of Paraloid B-72 in acetone was mixed with a 15% solution of Paraloid B-72 in ethyl acetate? Do these react on their own? Is it possible that the Paraloid could act as some kind of catalyst?

Comment: If you mix them you just have solution of Paraloid in mixed solvent, I don't see any reason to think it would be a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Paraloid® B72 as an adhesive for archaeological ceramics and other museum objects has been well established (Ref.1) as stated in the abstract:

> The proper preparation and application of Paraloid B-72 make it an excellent adhesive for archaeological ceramics and other materials. An understanding of the principles of adhesion is essential to the successful application of solvent adhesives.

Acetone is the most suitable solvent for the resin since its fast evaporation. Paraloid® B72 has replaced the cellulose nitrate lacquer used for many years in this purposes due to its long time stability (Ref.2). Other than acetone, Paraloid B-72  can be dissoved in other solvents such as toluene, xylene and ethanol, etc. The solvent effect (including that of ethyl acetate) on Paraloid B-72 has been studied and has not reported any adversary reactive nature (Ref.3).

Thus, the answer to OP's question, "Would there be any potentially dangerous byproducts produced if a 20% solution of Paraloid B-72 in acetone was mixed with a 15% solution of Paraloid B-72 in ethyl acetate?": Not necessarily as experimentally evidenced by these authors.

---

**References:**

1. Stephen P. Koob, "The use of Paraloid B-72 as an adhesive: its application for archaeological ceramics and other materials," *Studies in Conservation* **1986**, *31(1)*, 7-14 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1179/sic.1986.31.1.7).
2. Brigid Sullivan and Donald R. Cumberland, Jr., "Use Of Acryloid B-72 Lacquer For Labeling Museum Objects," *Conserve O Gram* **1993**, No.1/4, National Park Service Publication ([PDF](https://www.nps.gov/museum/publications/conserveogram/01-04.pdf)).
3. Armand Vinçotte, Emmie Beauvoit, Nicolas Boyard, and Elodie Guilminot, "Effect of solvent on PARALOID® B72 and B44 acrylic resins used as adhesives in conservation," *Heritage Science* **2019**, *7(42)*, 9 pages (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1186/s40494-019-0283-9).